# Obtaining predicted probabilities that include multiple random effects from mixed effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, prediction, glmm

I'm running a mixed effects logit model with a binary response variable. The data are cross-national survey data, over multiple waves (i.e., World Values Survey). As such, the random effects specified are countries, and countries are nested in waves. What I would like to do is provide predicted probabilities of `Y = 1` that include the upper and lower bound estimates that follow from including the random effects.

When there is just one random effect, I think this is process is fairly simple. The predicted probability is `exp(y)/ (1 + exp(y))`, where `y` is the predicted log odds of `y = 1`. The [upper/lower] bound is `exp(y [+/-] 1.96*stddev(re))/ (1 + exp(y [+/-] 1.96*stddev(re)))`, where `stddev(re)` is the standard deviation of the random effect.

However, I have more than one random effect, and nesting of random effects. I've tried to automate this process in the Zelig package, but the package wouldn't function properly. The next best thing is to do this manually. What is the correct way to compute the predicted probability from a mixed effects logit model, or think about it statistically? Any input would be appreciated. Sample output from my model follows.

```
Formula: y ~ x1 + x2 + g1 + g2 + (1 | country) + (1 | wave:country)

Random effects:
 Groups          Name     Variance Std.Dev.
 wave:country (Intercept) 0.14352  0.37883 
 country      (Intercept) 0.29666  0.54466 


(Intercept)           -2.4931203  0.2497937   -9.54  < 2e-16 ***
x1                     0.0012331  0.0006466    1.91 0.056498 .  
x2                    -0.0406811  0.0191837   -2.12 0.033954 * 
g1                     0.1386181  0.0672643    2.06 0.039322 *  
g2                    -0.0028760  0.0737821   -0.04 0.968907
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand your question. You wrote "What is the correct way to compute the predicted probability from a mixed effects logit model, or think about it statistically?" What is missing from the sample output to answer that question? Are you interested in the random effects?